# click doesnt trigger file upload dialog in firefox when inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, file-upload, postmessage

I have a bit of a complex scenario.
Im researching something for a POC im doing, where the eventual aim is to get files uploaded cross-domain while supporting IE 9.

I have my page say at:

http://app.ui/index.html

which loads an iframe say at:

http://app.upload/index.html

the second page (in the iframe) has a file input element and is listening to post-message events.

When a button is clicked on the "ui" page (in the first domain), the page sends a message to the iframe which in turn calls something like:

```
var upload = document.getElementById("fileupload");

  upload.click();
```

or

```
 var upload =  document.getElementById("fileupload");
 var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");

  evt.initEvent("click", true, true);

  upload.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Both examples work just fine in Chrome (37), the file upload dialog is opened and i can select a file from my computer.

In Firefox (31) however, this doesnt work. there is no error or anything but the click triggering just doesnt do anything. in FF 32 which I just upgraded to, i get a message saying that a popup was blocked even though I allowed popups for this domain.

It doesnt matter if the iframe is hidden or not by the way.

This is very frustrating because there doesnt seem like anything I can do code-wise to work around it.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

thanks!

Comment: can we access elements in an iframe which are in a different domain?

Comment: Nope, the browser prohibits access across domains